# Where to Add a folder in .net solution so that while building the project folder should be created?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Where to Add a folder in .net solution so that while building the project folder should be created?

Comment: Can you improve your phrasing, not really able to make sense of what you are asking.

Comment: could you explain briefly. what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face same issues as 
suppose i have one report folder with all the .rpt files and after building the project that Report folder need to be copied in debug or release folder based on debugging mode..

And i applied the same logic for Mkdir in Postbuild event and added another commands to copy the things from original location of folder to the new folder being created..

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a post-build step:

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)\MyDirectory
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a folder in the output directory as part of the build process. I see two ways to achieve that :

1. [Tweak your .csproj file using MSBuild tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) (specifically [MakeDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2448zz7.aspx)) :

   ```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild">
     <MakeDir Directories="$(TargetDir)\MyFolder" />
   </Target>
   ```
2. Use DOS commands in the post-build step : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, a folder won't be created if it doesn't have anything in it (at least, IIRC). I've added a 'blank.txt' to a folder before, and then you can just delete that, post-build.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean there, but generally speaking, creating a folder inside the solution only creates a virtual folder - no actual folder is created on your file system. If you want the actual folders to match the ones appearing in your solution, just manually create a folder using the windows explorer (Or any other way you like) at the same spot, using the same name.
I have no idea what those solution virtual folders are good for.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder isn't needed until runtime you can generally just do a `Directory.Exists` check for it in your program start up logic and create the folder(s) as required.

Otherwise a folder added to the solution has to have something in it which has Build Action of None (or Content I think) and which has the Copy to Output Directory property set